# Hibernate - how to display object list in JSP table?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jsp

I got table with couple columns, and I want in order to table will display all rows from database. But console says: `javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException: result returns more than one elements`

Here is a code:

```
EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("onlineshop");
    EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

    Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT iduser FROM lastloggeduser ORDER BY idlastloggeduser DESC LIMIT 1");
    String s = query.getSingleResult().toString();


    if (s != null){
        Query selectAll = entityManager.createQuery("FROM Product WHERE iduser=:iduser");   
        selectAll.setParameter("iduser", s);
        System.out.println(s);
        Product p = (Product) selectAll.getSingleResult();

            Product product = new Product();
            product.setID(p.getID());
            product.setProduct(p.getProduct());
            product.setName(p.getName());
            product.setCompany(p.getCompany());
            product.setType(p.getType());
            product.setPrice(p.getPrice());

            products.add(product);


    }
```

JSP:

```
<c:forEach var="product" items="${products}">
            <tr>
                <td>${product.getID()}</td>
                <td><img src="${product.getProduct()}" /></td>
                <td>${product.getName()}</td>
                <td>${product.getCompany()}</td>
                <td>${product.getType()}</td>
                <td>${product.getPrice()}$</td>
                <td><form action="/OnlineShop/cart/cart.html?selectedItem=${product.getID()}"  method="post"><input type="submit" value="Delete"/></form></td>
            </tr>
            </c:forEach>
```

When I add this:

```
    selectAll.setMaxResults(1);
```

It works fine, but in table appears only one row, what should I do it in order to display all rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException: result returns more than one elements
```

This indicates that the table has multiple rows for the same iduser.

```
    Product p = (Product) selectAll.getSingleResult();
```

Instead of expecting the single result, try for multiple values. using [list()](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#list())

```
List<Product> productsList = selectAll.list();
```

If that's not the case that you expect data to come, clean your database to contain a single row per iduser.

Comment: List<Product> products = (List<Product>) selectAll.getResultList();  - it works :)

Answer (score -1):

Use the Resultset to execute query and then iterate through the Resultset to add products one by one.